# How can I get this raku Muller Recurrence One-Liner to work?

Tags: math, raku

In a reply to my recent [blog post](https://p6steve.wordpress.com/2021/04/02/raku34-python19-extreme-math/), Markus H. replied with a very succinct code alternative, namely:

```
dd $_ for (4, 4.25, 108 – (815 – 1500 / * ) / * … *)[^30].kv
```

Sadly I cannot get this to work "out of the box" and get this error:

```
Confused
at /Users/stephenroe/Dropbox/RakuStuff/mullerrec/./mullerrec3.raku:27
------> dd $_ for (4, 4.25, 108⏏ – (815 – 1500 / * ) / * … *)[^30].kv
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
```

How can I fix this?

Here's the code that I can get to work (yes, my style is a bit different, but that's ok):

```
sub f(\y,\z) { 
    108 - ( (815 - 1500/z ) / y ) 
}
dd $_ for (4, 4.25, -> \z,\y {f(y,z)}  … ∞)[^30].kv;
```

As a follow up, I think I need to swap the params to f, but Markus has not done that, who is right? I am keen to know if that is a gotcha and, then the question is "how can I reverse the order by which whatever stars are consumed"?

Or maybe something like:

```
dd $_ for (4, 4.25, f(^z,^y) … ∞)[^30].kv;   #not legal
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** Cut/paste in the era of non-Unicode character sets was hopelessly fraught and getting worse – but at least it was typically *loudly* fraught so one got mojibake, making it obvious things had gone wrong. In the Unicode era it's a new ballgame. You need to `s/–/-/`.

Making that change, but also making some other changes to switch to a hopefully more insightful display, and switching to [`FatRat`](https://docs.raku.org/type/FatRat) calculation so the results are **100% accurate** with **unlimited precision**:

```
say sprintf "%-2s: %-24s %s / %s", .key, .value, |.value.nude

for (4.FatRat, 4.25, 108 - (815 - 1500 / * ) / * … *)[^30].pairs

0 : 4                        4 / 1
1 : 4.25                     17 / 4
2 : 4.470588                 76 / 17
3 : 4.644737                 353 / 76
4 : 4.770538                 1684 / 353
5 : 4.855701                 8177 / 1684
6 : 4.910847                 40156 / 8177
7 : 4.945537                 198593 / 40156
8 : 4.96696258               986404 / 198593
9 : 4.9800457                4912337 / 986404
10: 4.987979448              24502636 / 4912337
11: 4.9927702881             122336033 / 24502636
12: 4.99565589151            611148724 / 122336033
13: 4.99739126838            3054149297 / 611148724
14: 4.998433943945           15265963516 / 3054149297
15: 4.9990600719709          76315468673 / 15265963516
16: 4.9994359371468          381534296644 / 76315468673
17: 4.99966152410377         1907542343057 / 381534296644
18: 4.999796900713418        9537324294796 / 1907542343057
19: 4.999878135477931        47685459212513 / 9537324294796
20: 4.9999268795045999       238423809278164 / 47685459212513
21: 4.99995612706115774      1192108586037617 / 238423809278164
22: 4.999973676005712445     5960511549128476 / 1192108586037617
23: 4.999984205520272708     29802463602463553 / 5960511549128476
24: 4.9999905232822276594    149012035582781284 / 29802463602463553
25: 4.99999431395855959365   745059330625296977 / 149012035582781284
26: 4.99999658837125602371   3725294111260656556 / 745059330625296977
27: 4.999997953021356907988  18626462930705797793 / 3725294111260656556
28: 4.9999987718123113299994 93132291776736534004 / 18626462930705797793
29: 4.9999992630872057845553 465661390253305305137 / 93132291776736534004
```

Muller's Recurrence is an approximation. But the accuracy/precision of a given iteration is determined by the accuracy/precision of prior iterations. These are in turn affected by the accuracy/precision of the numeric type(s) and operations used:

- Using floating point numbers / operations yields useless results after the 12th or so iteration.
- Using fixed point numbers / operations yields accurate results as long as numbers remain within their precision, and then quickly thereafter yields useless results.
- In my variant of @Holli's code I've used Raku's [`FatRat`](https://docs.raku.org/type/FatRat) number type and operations. This maintains 100% accuracy with unlimited precision. Even cheap hardware will easily do in the order of a 1,000 iterations, with 100% accuracy, in less than a second.

The Muller's Recurrence formula *mathematically* involves only rational numbers and operations ("rational" includes integers). Numeric operations in Raku conveniently follow [rules of "infection"](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Numeric_infectiousness) such that if:

- At least *one* of the numbers in each iteration is a `FatRat`;
- *None* of the numbers is a `Num` (floating point);
- No *operation* introduces a `Num` (floating point);

then each iteration will produce another 100% accurate `FatRat`.

This is true when Muller's Recurrence formula is used as is in Raku provided one of the numbers is coerced to a `FatRat`.

Comment: dear raiph - that is very helpful - thanks! (although a bit embarrassing that I cannot cut & paste unicode ... @markus was right about the non reversal ... as future reference, can one reverse whatever stars?

Comment: @p6steve No, you can't reverse stars. You have to use braces. For example `4, 4.25.FatRat, { 108 - (815 - 1500 / $^foo ) / $^bar } … *` will reverse the parameters/arguments because `bar` sorts lexicographically before `foo`.

Comment: raiph, I was using dd, because it displays the Rats as numerator/denominator and so shows where we start to lose precision.

Comment: @Holli I've edited my answer in response to your comment. Hopefully the edits make it clearer what I was trying to convey, one part of which is that the variant I used (adding a `.FatRat`) does not lose precision.

Comment: I've added a PR today to introduce a `$*RAT-UPGRADE-CLASS` dynamic variable, that allows one to indicate how upgrading from `Rat` can be handled: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4299 .  With that, you could leave out the `4.FatRat` when you would add `my $*RAT-UPGRADE-CLASS = FatRat` to your code (which would cause an upgrade to `FatRat` rather than a downgrade to `Num` when the denominator exceeds 64 bits).

Comment: @p6steve You may be able to reverse the effects of the stars using `R` meta operator. `* R/ *` is the same as `-> $a, $b { $b / $a }`.

Comment: thanks to all for excellent and comprehensive answers!